# How to implement an AJAX form and render a template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I will describe an app that consists of an AJAX form, that also works with Javascript disabled.

When submiting, if Javascript is disabled, it renders a new template called "created".
If Javascript is enabled, it should render it as well, but I don't know how to do it.

**Please note** that the template does not have a controller action nor a route, it is just displayed using the same route as the form.

Files:

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb
app/views/users/new.html.erb
app/views/users/created.html.erb
```

users_controller.rb:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :created }
    format.js { render js: ??? }
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, remote: true %>
  <%= email_field_tag :email %>

  <%= submit_tag "OK" %>
<% end %>
```

created.html.erb:

```
<div>
  Inside this file there is a big template to be rendered.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `create.js.erb` file in `views/users` and put the content there.

Then just call `format.js` from de controller.

For a complete example, see this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Comment: I already know how to do that, but I want to reuse my existing created.html.erb template. Putting my html code inside create.js.erb will not be rendered automatically.

Comment: In the `create.js.erb` you can do something like `$(".form").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render '/users/created') %>");` (assuming you use jQuery).

Comment: I think Florent2's suggestion is interesting.